# My flask app login does not work properly

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that works great on laptops/desktops but on mobile phone and small screens the login route doesn't work properly.

When I want to login to my app on a mobile phone the login page redirects to itself and nothing happen. I think this problem is somehow related to session or login decorated function. Sometimes it works suddenly but it doesn't response often.

What can I do now?

Here is my app heads and login route:

```
from cs50 import SQL
from math import ceil
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from helpers import intro_alert, main_alert, login_required, usd, ex_separator, separator, \
                    cmc_logo, exchange_rates, cmc_quote, cmc_listing, cmc_info, exchanges, exchange_pairs, cmc_projects


coinjito = Flask(__name__)
coinjito.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True


@coinjito.after_request
def after_request(response):

    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"

    return response


coinjito.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
coinjito.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
coinjito.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(coinjito)

@coinjito.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():

    session.clear()

    if request.method == "GET":

        return render_template("login.html")

    else:

        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username",
                          username=request.form.get("username"))

        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["password"], 
                                                     request.form.get("password")):

            return intro_alert("Apology", "alert-danger", "Login Failed",
                             "Invalid username and/or password.", "/login", "Go Back")

        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
        session["username"] = rows[0]["username"]

        return redirect("/tracking")

@coinjito.route("/tracking")
@login_required
```

And here is my login helper function:

```
def login_required(f):

    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):

        if session.get("user_id") is None:

            return redirect("/login")

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

Comment: Have you checked in your desktop with developer mode [F12]  in your browser? so you say it does not work with a small screen.?

Comment: It seems removing "config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()" from app gets it to work but I don't now what is the actual problem. I only know that in mobile browsers the "session.get("user_id")" statement returns None.

Comment: the matter may relate to privacy in your mobile, because of does not allow to `mkdtemp()`